# Spring IntegrationFlow IBM MQ Webflux - How to manually acknowledge message

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using IBM MQ and want to have messages pushed into my application's Webflux code, so I can process a message
I've defined an IntegrationFlow @Bean

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveMQConfig {

  @Value("${ibm.mq.inQueueName}")
  private String inQueueName;

  @Value("${ibm.mq.channel}")
  private String channel;

  @Bean
  public Publisher<Message<String>> mqMessageFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(
            Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                .configureListenerContainer(x ->
                    x.backOff(new FixedBackOff(1000, 1000000))
                    .concurrentConsumers(1)
                    .maxConcurrentConsumers(1)
                    .sessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
                )
                .destination(inQueueName))
        .channel(channel)
        .log()
        .toReactivePublisher();
  }

}
```

This allows me to get messages via the messageDrivenChannelAdapter into Webflux.
And I perform operations on the messages by autowiring the flow as a bean into my service like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MQListener {

    @Autowired
    Publisher<Message<String>> mqIntegrationFlow;

    @PostConstruct
    public void listen() {
        Flux.from(mqIntegrationFlow).flatMap(m -> this.handleMessage(m.getPayload())).subscribe();
    }
            
    public Flux<SenderResult<Void>> handleMessage(String incomingMessage) {
        return Flux.just(incomingMessage)
          .flatMap(myclass1::someOperation1)
          .flatMap(myclass2::lastOperation1)
          .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Everything works"))
          .doOnError(throwable -> { log.error("OUTPUT: "+throwable.getMessage()); throwable.printStackTrace(); Mono.just(throwable).log("OUTPUT"+throwable.getMessage(), Level.SEVERE); });
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having is I don't have a clue how to **MANUALLY** acknowledge a message.

The interface for the Message I'm receiving is GenericMessage and that doesn't have an acknowledge() method on it as I've seen with Kafka.

I've seen AMQ and Kafka use headers from the message and utilise something like AMQHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGE such as...

```
Acknowledgment acknowledgment = m.getHeaders().get(MQHeader)
```

Can someone help me out as to how I can manually acknowledge or not depending on success / fail of the message processing?

Thanks all.